# Provider contacts is always in use and because Android Core Apps (android.process.acore) not released after querying Contacts Provider

Tags: android, memory, contacts

My app queries the contacts content provider to display a list of frequent contacts (using the Contacts.CONTENT_STREQUENT_URI) and their photos (Data.CONTENT_URI). The cursor returned from the query is always closed in a finally block.

However, when inspecting in the Settings -> Apps -> RUNNING, there are always 2 processes for my app, and one of them is Android Core Apps (android.process.acore) which takes up about 10 extra MB and makes my app look bulky.

Is there anything I can do to disconnect my app with the contacts content provider after I finish my queries?

Answer (score 0):

`android.process.acore` is  a system process for your contacts. See what xda has to say here -->

[xda-android-acore](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=37286991)

I don't think there is anything wrong with your app in this case.

Also for a comprehensive guide to checking your android app's memory footprint check out-->

[How do I discover memory usage of my application in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android/2299813#2299813)